# Can I invoke casting error when casting int types?

Tags: c#, casting

it is a bit unusual question but I am unable to get casting error when casting numeric types. I would need to get some error like "value too short" etc. but seems that C# guards it quite well.
Could you provide me with a simple code that fails on casting? (like stackoverflow..)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you expect? When casting an integer to short, you explicit say "I know int is larger, I know this cast can have data loss, I want it anyway."

Comment: Yes, I want to see the error anyway. I just expect to get a runtime error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) keyword to explicitly check for overflow of integral type conversions:

```
int i = int.MaxValue;
short s = checked((short)i);
```

There is also a [checked compiler flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx) which can make checked conversions the default.

Answer (score 0):

> Could you provide me with a simple code that fails on casting?

```
int i = 400;
object o = i; // here o will be System.Int32 automatically

string s = (string)o; //Runtime Exception thrown System.InvalidCastException:
```

Comment: @user970696 i have update my answer and it will throw error at runtime  when casting o to string

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to write some error handling code.  The compiler does do a great job of watching for inappropriate casts, but if you're looking for a runtime exception:

```
short y = short.Parse("56789");
```

This will throw an `OverflowException`.

> OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an
>   Int16.